# IIS7 Redirect Rule change country alias in friendly urls

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

At the moment I have a alias as such

```
http://mysite/ru/folder/pagename
```

and i want to redirect to

```
http://mysite/us/folder/pagename
```

So in IIS7 I was trying to use URL Rewrite

a sample url can look like

```
http://mysite/ru/Solutions/Education+Solutions
```

how would the rule for the above look like

Answer (score 0):

The follow code should do it for you

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="http://mysite/ru/folder/pagename">
                <match url="http://mysite/[a-z]{2}/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://mysite/us/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This breaks down to be

- `[a-z]{2}` Any two letter country code
- `(.*)` Zero or more characters
- `{R:1}` a back reference to the (.*) the () mark it as a group

Comment: cool will try that out man..I was just trying something for a specific url as well..Pattern was ^/Solutions/Education+Solutions/ and url I tested was http://www.mysite.com/Solutions/Education+Solutions/ but it said input data to test does not match pattern any ideas why ?

Comment: If your using regex the + sign is a reserved character it means 1 or more. change it to \+